# No Django settings specified

Tags: python, django, linux

Buenas tardes,
Estoy intentando de crear mi proyecto en Django pero al ejecutar el comando "django-admin createproyect nombre_proyecto" me da el siguiente error:

> No Django settings specified.
>   Unknown command: 'createproyect'
>   Type 'django-admin.py help' for usage.

También lo he probado poniendo antes "python django-admin.py createproyect nombre".
Espero que me podáis ayudar, gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Ese comando no existe, es

```
django-admin startproject nombre_proyecto
```

Comment: Zezaru, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Pero la respuesta es correcta. No hay otra forma de contestar, ni se requieren de más caracteres porque solo agregarían ruido a la respuesta.

Comment: No se de dónde he sacado lo de createproyect pero de todas maneras he probado con startproyect y me dice exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Hola @manuxdjent, si te dice exactamente lo mismo es que sigues usando `createproyect`, debes usar __`startproject`__.

Comment: @toledano vale, estaba poniendo todo el rato 'startproyect' , vaya tela jaja de todas formas gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Si @manuxdjent, ya propuse esta pregunta para cierre.